# Catching a specific exception on a drop column CQL statement in Clojure

Tags: clojure, cql, cassandra-3.0

I want to run a drop-column CQL statement on a table that may or may not have that column exist. Ideally I would like to do a if-exists then drop column, but I do not believe CQL supports that.

My work around is to catch an invalid query exception, but that is not working and I cannot figure out why. In the following code, the generic Except will hit giving the message "*com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.InvalidQueryException: Column my_col was not found in table my_table*". I have no idea why my InvalidQueryException is not hitting.

```
(ns my-namespace
  (:require [qbits
              [alia :as alia]
              [hayt :as hayt]]))

(defn prepared-statement
  [session]
  (try
     (alia/execute session
                   (hayt/alter-table :my_table
                                     (hayt/drop-column :my_col)))
     (catch com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.InvalidQueryException ie
       (prn "your column doesn't exist"))
     (catch Exception e
       (prn (ex-data e)))))
```

Answer (score 2):

Look at [the source](https://github.com/mpenet/alia/blob/master/modules/alia/src/qbits/alia.clj#L251) for `alia/execute`. As you can see, it already contains [its own `try` `catch` block](https://github.com/mpenet/alia/blob/master/modules/alia/src/qbits/alia.clj#L322) with only `Exception`.

So, you have to call [`execute`](https://docs.datastax.com/en/drivers/java/4.0/com/datastax/oss/driver/api/core/CqlSession.html#execute-java.lang.String-) method of `CqlSession` (and use `hayt/->raw` to create query string):

```
(:import (com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.servererrors InvalidQueryException))

(defn prepared-statement
  [session]
  (try (.execute session
              (hayt/->raw (hayt/alter-table :my_table
                                            (hayt/drop-column :my_col))))
    (catch InvalidQueryException ie
      (prn "your column doesn't exist"))
    (catch Exception e
      (prn (ex-data e)))))
```

Test:

```
(prepared-statement s)
"your column doesn't exist"
=> nil
```